# macOS Big Sur can't remove ghost icon from deleted application

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur, launchpad, alias

I've deleted TextMate and its alias from Launchpad and Library - still have a "ghost" icon showing in all windows (see screenshot).

[image: TextMate alias icon]

When I enter Launchpad that ghost icon (in last screen) won't delete even when the option key is held down and icon quivers.

If I scroll to first Launchpad screen the ghost icon automatically appears as the last item in that window, then auto-scrolls to next screen where ghost icon moves to last item again, etc. until it shows in the last Launchpad window by itself.

I've used AVG Cleaner with no change, ran the reindex option for Finder with no change.

Essentially, I can't use Launchpad since it auto-scrolls from any screen to the last screen with the ghost icon of "TextMate alias".

Any thoughts?

Comment: I only see text, no icon, so it's probably just a graphical error. Have you restarted the computer? I know there's a file you can delete which has the organization settings for Launchpad, you might want to look into that.

Comment: I was only able to post one image - the other images provide more details. Yeah - I've restarted and have re-indexed the system drive.

Comment: The above image shows just the application title "TextMate alias" with an empty image. Essentially, my list of LaunchPad application are not accessible because the Mac auto-scrolls through each "tab" leaving off at a separate window with just the icon ghost sitting there.

Comment: Oop - I did an Symantec AV update and the the ghost icon is gone, Launchpad behaves normally!